# Flask route for AngularJS with HTML5 URL mode

Tags: angularjs, flask

I have an AngularJS app being served via Flask. I am using the HTML5 routing mode and thus need to redirect several URLs to the client app. I'm not sure how to do the wildcard matching needing to do this correctly. Currently I just match multiple levels of path like this:

```
@app.route('/ui/')
def ui():
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')
@app.route('/ui/<path>')
def ui(path):
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')
@app.route('/ui/<path>/<path2>')
def ui(path,path2):
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')
```

Obviously I don't like this and would like to just have one route (everything starting with `ui/`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The path [url converter](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#url-route-registrations) can do this for you:

```
@app.route('/ui/<path:p>')
def ui(p):
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')
```