# static_url_path and variable rules

Tags: python, flask

[Variable rules](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#variable-rules) isn't working as I'd expect when [`static_url_path`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#application-object) is used.

Simply, why does this work:

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", defaults={"p": "")
@app.route("/<path:p>")
def main(p):
    return "<h1>Hello %s</h1>" % p


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But not this?

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__, static_url_path="")

@app.route("/", defaults={"p": "")
@app.route("/<path:p>")
def main(p):
    return "<h1>Hello %s</h1>" % p


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

> Note the added `static_url_path`

Some background details; I'm new to both Flask and AngularJS, but are using them here in conjunction with each other and for those not familiar with AngularJS; I'm using AngularJS to produce a single-page application in which paths are used for dynamically replacing content within a document, as opposed to reloading the whole page. Thus, I need all paths routed to the same html document (not included in the above example), ideally coming form the same function, so as to let AngularJS handle rendering as opposed to Flask.

The below answer solved that issue, but it isn't working when `status_url_path` is used, and I can't figure out why.

[Flask route for AngularJS with HTML5 URL mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539056/flask-route-for-angularjs-with-html5-url-mode)

Adding this for reference, as he is doing this exact thing.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2geC50roans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are effectively telling Flask to map `/<path:static_path>` to static files. That means that **everything** is now considered static. Don't do this!

Angular pages don't need to call into Flask static routes; keep your static routes under `/static`, have `/` produce your Angular application, then use other routes to handle Angular AJAX calls. These can have proper paths; Angular doesn't dictate what routes your Flask server will respond to.

Then keep your static route to serve the JavaScript and CSS and images, e.g. the actual static content referenced from your HTML page.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, I'll try and wrap my head around this and get back to you.

Comment: Seems to work fine. To be clear, this also means that all addresses, including those to AngularJS controllers, must include the flask "static/" directory? E.g. `templateUrl: "static/views/list.html"`

Comment: @MarcusOttosson: yes, if those parts are static (e.g. the Flask server only has to produce the file data, not insert anything in a template or produce other dynamic info).